# Vector assign() causing issues with back()

Tags: c++, vector, reference, invalidation

Just practicing with some code challenges and ran into a weird issue. I have a global method that prints the content of a vector with a ", " after every index but the last. I then assign() new values to the vector and call the method again but the back() reference after the second call is funky. Here is the main driver code:

```
...
std::vector<int> v = {-2, -1, 1, 2};
printV(v);

v.assign({1, 2, 3, 4});
printV(v);
...
```

The 'printV()' method looks like this:

```
void printV(const std::vector<int> v) {
 for(auto&& i : v) {
  std::cout << i;
  if (i != v.back()) {
   std::cout << ", ";
  }
 }
}
```

So the first call on 'printV()' works just fine and prints '-2, -1, 1, 2'. However, the second call after the 'v.assign({...})' seems to cause 'v.back()' to reference the first element and the last element and prints this: '12, 3, 4'. I looked at the method details for assign() and I think it might have something to do with reference invalidation but I am not really sure what that means or how it works. Any help is much appreciated.

CM

Comment: Unrelated to this specific issue, but what if the vector contains more than one element equal to its last element? `i` isn't an index, it's an element. So if the vector is `{1, 2, 3, 1}`, `1 == v.back()` both times it appears.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/E1zn6d. I don't see `12, 3, 4` anywhere.